# Building hash from xml, error in rspec test

Tags: ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I've been trying for some time now to build hash from xml response, but i keep getting this error

> ```
>  Failure/Error: expect(Hash.from_xml(resp_body)).to eq({
>  SyntaxError:
>    ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rexml/functions.rb:393:
> ```
>
> syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input

`response.body` is

`"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><response> 
 <txn_id>123</txn_id>  <result>0</result>  <comment>OK</comment> 
 <filial>1</filial>  <prv_txn type=\"integer\">1</prv_txn></response>"`

rspec itself:

```
require 'rails_helper'   
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/conversions'  
describe TestController do  
   it 'should invoke pay_action' do  
     do_pay_request  
     resp_body =  response.body.gsub /\n/, ''  
     expect(Hash.from_xml(resp_body)).to eq({  
                                                   response: {  
                                                       txn_id: '123456789101',  
                                                       prv_txn: '111',  
                                                       result: '0',  
                                                       comment: 'OK',  
                                                       filial: '1'  
                                                   }.stringify_keys  
                                               }.stringify_keys)  

   end   
end
```

I'm using rvm with ruby `ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by adding `gem 'rubysl-rexml', '~> 2.0.2'` to my gemfile